# How can I format a string in android

Tags: android

I would to create a string with the value of 'anInteger' and append with a string from string.xml.  This is what i am doing:

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(anInteger);
    sb.append(" ");
    sb.append(getString(R.string.aString));
```

I wonder if there is a clearer or easier way to do that in android?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare your resource like this:

```
<string name="aString">%1$s something</string>
```

Then you just do:

```
getString(R.string.aString, anInteger);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define string resource containing string formatting tags e.g. `"%d some text"`. Then in code use `getString(R.string.aString, anInteget)`.

Comment: There is no need to use String.format since getString can do it.

Comment: What do you mean? I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

Do it the java way! :D

```
String str = Integer.toString(anInteger);
```

this is how I do it.
then ofcourse afterwards:

```
str += getString(R.string.aString);
```